# Update Progress Bar While Inserting Data Into Database

Tags: asp.net, progress-bar, updateprogress

```
foreach (DataRow row in Employee.Rows)
{
    //insert record into database. when record entered i need to update the progress 
    //bar on client side.
}
```

How to solve my Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your Insert Button in `Update Panel` and assign `Update Progress` to your `Update Panel` as shown below.

```
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="Images/loading.gif" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```